# Access column value of each row iterating through a loop and sum all of values of each row

Tags: python, pandas

*### Access column value of each row iterating through a loop and sum all of values of each row. ###*

**df**

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

**code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("df.csv")
 
def add(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

for i in range (0,df.columns.size):
    add(df.col1.get(i), df.col2.get(i), df.col3.get(i))
```

*This is not yielding any results.*

**Desired output is :**

```
6
15
24
```

Comment: You never do _anything_ with the return value of `add` ...

Comment: ``df.sum(axis=1)`` ?

Comment: actually I wanted to know how to access column value for each row iterating through a loop so I've framed a question like this.

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: add(x['a'], x['b'], x['c']), axis=1)`

Comment: ```for i in range(len(df)):
    s = np.sum([df.loc[i,col] for col in df])
    print(s)``` The question is closed. Hope this helps !!

Comment: @cs95 `df.apply(lambda x: add(x['a'], x['b'], x['c']), axis=1)` works - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum using axis=1.

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

You can use apply it will send each row to the function. You can pick any column you want to add them up.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2], axis=1)
```

Comment: yes `df.sum(axis=1)` does the work but actually I wanted to know how to access column element for each row iterating through a loop so I've framed a question like this

Comment: Why didn't it work? Do you have some other columns?

Comment: I didn't say you you answer will not work, it does. But I wanted to do through other way.

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: add(x['a'], x['b'], x['c']), axis=1)` - this is what I wanted. Thanks